# Can I ignore the warning: "tests made without re-estimating 'theta'" from an analysis of deviance test of a negative binomial model?

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm new to R and don't know how to deal with this warning I get while doing negative binomial log regression:

> `Warning in anova.negbin(nb.MouthOpen) : tests made without re-estimating 'theta'`

Can I ignore this or does it have an effect on the results I get? The data are behavioral observations made by a 1-0 sample method and is then compared against a noseband tightness score.

```
summary(nb.MouthOpen <- with(Noseband, glm.nb(cbind(MouthOpen, Totalscans-MouthOpen) ~ 
                                                TightnessNoseband))
anova(nb.MouthOpen)
(est <- cbind(Estimate = coef(nb.MouthOpen), confint(nb.MouthOpen)))
exp(est)
deviance(nb.MouthOpen)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please provide more information about your situation, your data, your goals, & the model. It is difficult to answer this question without more information.

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, I think that's enough.  Why are you using a negative binomial model?  The use of `cbind(events, total-events)` is suspicious.  It looks like you have binomial (response) data, not count data.

Comment: If this is `MASS::glm.nb`, I can't even get it to run with a two-column response.

Comment: Because my thesis supervisor told me that negative binomial was the right model for my data. I guess 1-0 method results would be regarded as count? I have a number of 1's that I add up and use the total score in this analysis