# What does this warning mean?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

I'm new to R and don't know how to deal with this warning I get while doing negative binomial log regression:

Warning in anova.negbin(nb.MouthOpen) : tests made without re-estimating 'theta'

Can I ignore this or does it have an effect on the results I get?

I have no idea of what kind of information you need to help me...does the code help? The data are behavioural observations made by a 1-0 sample method and is then compared against a noseband tightness score. It's for my master thesis.

summary(nb.MouthOpen <- glm.nb(cbind(NosebandMouthOpen,NosebandTotalscans-NosebandMouthOpen) Noseband TightnessNoseband, data = Noseband))

anova(nb.MouthOpen)

(est <- cbind(Estimate = coef(nb.MouthOpen), confint(nb.MouthOpen)))

exp(est)

deviance(nb.MouthOpen)

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [Can I ignore this warning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476381/can-i-ignore-this-warning)

Comment: It was closed and it didn't help editing it, so thought I had to make a new post. I'm new to forums as well...

Comment: The [help] has information about how to use this website.